# Apollo Client Error, Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: async-await, graphql, apollo-client, next.js

I'm getting a weird error when attempting to do async/await on my graphql query. Not sure what to do here.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ApolloConsumer } from 'react-apollo';
import Landing from '../modules/landing/index.js';
import getUser from '../shared/services/get-user';

export default class extends Component {
  checkLoggedIn = async (client) => {
    const response = await getUser(client);
    console.log(response);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloConsumer>
        {client => (
          <div>
            {this.checkLoggedIn(client)}
            <Landing />
          </div>
        )}
      </ApolloConsumer>
    )
  }
}
```

If I remove the async await syntax, the app proceeds to execute my getUser query. However, when I try to do this with async/await. My app shows the error above. Is there something about ApolloConsumer that I do not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because `async` function returns a promise. And, you are trying to render a promise inside of the render method. This isn't Apollo specific error, React simply doesn't allow this.

The reason why it works when you don't have the `async` there is because the function returns `undefined` which react treats as `null` in the render method and doesn't render anything.